# Kill all processes in a listBox? (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, process, listbox, kill

I'm trying to create a small productivity program to keep myself focused when programming; specifically, to close any processes that might distract me from doing my job.  I'm writing it in VB.NET for simplicity.

What is the easiest way to kill all processes listed in a listBox?  I already know how to add the processes to my listBox with this code:

```
        Dim newProc As New OpenFileDialog

    '// Settings for the open file dialog. (I like how I use ' to start the comment, but // so I recognize it! :)

    newProc.Filter = "Executable files (*.exe)|*.exe"
    newProc.FileName = "..choose a file.."
    newProc.Multiselect = True
    newProc.CheckFileExists = True
    newProc.CheckPathExists = True
    newProc.AutoUpgradeEnabled = True
    newProc.AddExtension = True

    If (newProc.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(newProc.SafeFileNames)
    End If
```

This adds the processes to the listBox very neatly and all, exactly how I want it.  I have a timer that gets enabled with the press of a button that should close all processes in the listBox, but I'm unsure what I should use.  Can I get some help? :(

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim pProcess() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")

For Each p As Process In pProcess
   p.Kill()
Next
```

You can try the above. Please view this [link](http://vbnetsample.blogspot.com/2007/08/start-and-kill-process.html) for further infomation.

Comment: That will only close the notepad process.  I am trying to kill all processes in a listBox.

Comment: It's just an Example to get you started. All you need to do is pass in the values of the listbox where "notepad" is.

Comment: That's where I'm having troubles. :(

Comment: I've tried quite a few approaches, and none of them are working.  Does anyone have any ideas? :(

Comment: Aha, got it!! -  ' For Each proc In ListBox1.Items
            Dim pp() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(proc.ToString.ToLower().Split(".")(0))
            For Each p As Process In pp
                p.Kill()
            Next
        Next'